# Escape underscore column name in Access ODBC Query

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have some names like this in an MS Access database (under ColdFusion):

```
old_id, old_name
```

when I try to select them I get the following error:

```
[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

my query was:

```
select TOP 10 id, old_id, name, old_name from tablename WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

tried to escape the underscores in my queries to:

```
select TOP 10 [id],[old_id],[name],[old_name] from [tablename] WHERE [id] IS NOT NULL
```

even:

```
(select TOP 10 [id],[old_id],[name],[old_name] from [tablename] WHERE [id] IS NOT NULL)
```

still same error. Any idea?

Comment: You have a typo in one of your column names.

Comment: What's the typo and what's wrong? Why can't I escape them?

Comment: You don't need to escape the underscore in the first place, it's not a special character. When Access asks for a parameter it's usually a sign that you've used a column name in your query that does not exist. Most of the time that means typo. Double check your SQL.

Comment: You were right, I had "old_cid" not "old_id"! Please answer so I accet the answer! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, no need. :) Just beef up your own answer a little and accept it as soon as it's technially possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments above, my answer to this question is:

"When writing SQL queries, spelling counts." :)